# If there is a list of English rhyming words, syllable count, or parts of speech for free download (public domain)

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Wondering if there is a list of English words for free download (i.e. public domain, not creative commons), that contain either rhyming words, the syllable count/breakdown for the word, or the part of speech. Perhaps it is in the form of a:

- Dictionary
- Word frequency list
- Corpus annotation

Wondering if anything such exists. Preferably not ShareALike or Creative Commons as it has restrictions. But would still be good to know of Creative Commons examples in case a public domain version doesn't exist.

I have found a list of english *words* (no definitions), but nothing like rhymes/syllable count/POS.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are looking for:

- all of these. That is, you want a word list with pronunciation *and* part(s) of speech.
- it seems you also want frequency.
- file(s) that is easily manipulable programmatically.

You could cobble these all together from different sources (say from [cmudict](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict)) for pronunciation, or many places for [a part of speech word list](https://www.google.com/search?q=part+of+speech+word+list), but there is one source that has a bunch of those files together:

> [Moby word lists](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3201)

I don't know the quality, it's not being updated anymore, and you'll have to extend it yourself to get 'rhyming' (just search for ends of words matching the end of your target word).

Be prepared to deal with pronunciation variations. I think cmudict and moby both follow GenAmE, which is not necessarily your target audience. It is theoretically possible to programmatically 'translate' to other accents (using [lexical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) and a [possible mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)), but I think it will be difficult to implement.